# Can the execution of ABAP code be triggered from an HTML page via Javascript?

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori, webdynpro

To visualize it a bit better, assume this nonsense example:

- A simple, freestyle HTML/CSS/JS page is served via an HTTP service in ICF.
- The page was populated with data from SPFLI, i. e. an HTML table is displayed showing all the entries from the database table (including the carrid field).
- A button is implemented on the page to trigger an event.
- An entry of the HTML table is selected. Clicking the button triggers the execution of ABAP code, for example like this: The carrid value of the selected table line is passed and based on this value, some ABAP code should be executed (e.g. a SELECT on SFLIGHT/SCARR based on the passed carrid value is executed to populate another table on the page or whatever).

These are my questions:

- Is something in this direction possible at all?
- If not such a freestyle HTML/CSS/JS page, what would be the best technology to do it (UI5, Webdynpro ...) to do further research (Note: it is not meant for a "productive app", rather playing around)?
- Are there any recommendations for demos, tutorials or links especially concerning the ABAP code execution triggering and value passing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a web application to communicate with an ABAP backend, then you would usually do that through a webservice exposed by the application server.

There are several ways to implement webservices in SAP ABAP. The classic way to do that would be an [enterprise service](https://help.sap.com/viewer/684cffda9cbc4187ad7dad790b03b983/201909.002/en-US/66af86f384b747cf8c4607840e565eeb.html). But the current state-of-the-art would be an [OData](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Data_Protocol)-compliant webservice with the [RESTful programming model](https://help.sap.com/viewer/fc4c71aa50014fd1b43721701471913d/201909.001/en-US).

The web frontend *could* be implemented via UI5, which offers really elegant ways to bind UI controls to a data model backed by an oData webservice. But if you don't want to bother with the huge dependency and arduous learning curve of SAPUI5 / OpenUI5, then you can just as well communicate with an oData-webservice via the usual vanilla-JS tools (`XmlHttpRequest` / `fetch(url)`).

Comment: Thanks. Will then further research on the topic. If s.o. has right away a straightforward tutorial/blog to get one's hands dirty quickly, most welcome. Regarding RAP, I assume the ABAP code is then implemented in a behavior pool.

Comment: @Brix The tutorials and blog posts I would recommend to you are the same ones Google would recommend. If you mean the restful programming model with RAP: That's implemented as an ABAP class and a bunch of other artifacts you have to create via the ABAP development tools in Eclipse.  If you have any further questions, feel free to post them.

Comment: For a minimalistic and very old school feel, google SAP BSP